# Lazyweb cypher "Request Failed, Check authorization settings"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import a lot of cypher queries into my Neo4j server using the LazyWeb Cypher http://www.lyonwj.com/LazyWebCypher/.

I have uploaded the file where the cypher queries are present in the format

```
MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4026})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);
MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4027})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4028})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4029})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4030})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4031})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);

MATCH (f:PERSON{userid:3980}), (h:PERSON{userid:4032})with f,h CREATE (f)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(h);
```

These are all relationships. 
I have provided the default id and password , However, while trying to run the queries, it is giving me the error, "Request Failed, Check Authorization Settings".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have either entered the id or the password wrong.
http://www.lyonwj.com/LazyWebCypher/ here in Run that Cypher.

Recheck it, remember, default is neo4j/neo4j. Also, neo4j prompts you to change password after first use.